Xfce4 Suspend action button keeps ignoring my Suspend customization
Apparently, Suspend action button from Panel uses systemctl suspend (code), but keeps ignoring my customized systemctl suspend command.
I have created a script that I put under /usr/loca/bin folder:
#!/bin/bash

case $@ in
    suspend)
        canberra-gtk-play -i desktop-suspend
        /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout -s
        ;;
    *)
        /usr/bin/systemctl $@
        ;;
esac

Command works normally in Terminal.
How to force Suspend action button uses my own version?
